# GAE Application app.yaml VS .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine

How to Write a app yaml looks like htacess below

```
    RewriteEngine on
    # To append a query string part in the substitution string
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)/$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
```

im doing so at app yaml for GAE Application was fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Dan mentioned, you will not be able to handle this all in the yaml, and will need to to handle the logic yourself, we do a simular thing in one of our project and will outline below our solution.

Our scenario is handling the old website article's URL structure, and trying to redirect them to the new URL structure.

In our yaml we register the pattern that we are looking to match on and direct it to a file where we will do the handling :

```
- url: (/.*/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/.*)  (Pattern to match on)
  script: publication.custom.redirector.app (Path to your .py that will have your handling in)
```

In our .py file we will catch that pattern and route it to our DefaultHandler that can then do any logic you need and redirect out: 
( in our project this goes to /publication/custom/redirector.py )

```
import request
import settings
import re

class DefaultHandler(request.handler):

    def get(self, pre, year, month, day, post):

        post = re.sub('(.*[^0-9])[\d]{1}$', r'\1', post)
        post = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z-_\/]+', '', post)
        path = post.split("/")[-1]
        slug = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}".format(year, month, day, path)

        article = self.context.call('pub/articles/get', slug=slug.lower())
        if article:
            self.redirect(article['pub_url'], permanent=True)
        else:
            self.render("pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.html")


app = request.app([
    ('/(.*)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)', DefaultHandler)
], settings.gaext.config)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The GAE `app.yaml` doesn't have a URL rewrite capability, it just parses the incoming request URL for request routing purposes, to determine which handlers to invoke.

One could maybe argue that the `static_file` handlers configuration has a somewhat similar capability, but it is only applicable to the static assets.

For the dynamic handlers you'd need to take care of such "rewrite" inside your app code. I'm quoting "rewrite" here as technically it's just a different way of parsing/interpreting the request URL inside your app code - the original, unchanged request URL will still be the one recorded by the GAE infra.

Comment: i didnt know how to write it at app.yaml
it stil confuse how to redirect my URL to another folder called "mymodule"
its look fine if using .htacess

Comment: Here My app.yaml
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: elearning

handlers:

# Example of handler which should be placed above the catch-all handler.
- url: /module
  static_dir: module


- url: /.*
  script: index.php

Comment: You shouldn't put code in the comments - unreadable. Instead edit your post and place it in there. Also explain what exactly are you trying to achieve (examples would be good) - I'm not familiar with detailed .htaccess operation.